# VB.Net Date String Format Patterns

Tags: vb.net, string, datetime, format

DateTime.Now to **Jul 31 10:20:30 PST 2012** format

```
DirectCast(row(0), DateTime).ToString("ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'PST' yyyy")
```

`row(0)` is a string that is in the format `7/29/2012 1:25:20 PM`

Keeps telling me the **cast is incorrect**, how can I correctly cast the string?

Awesome [link](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm) for patterns for datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse.aspx), [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx), [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx).

I suspect you could use `CType` instead of `DirectCast`, but personally I'd go for the method call - it makes it clearer what you're doing.